# Motivação para OWIN

Tags: asp.net, owin

Esses dias li sobre OWIN no site da MSDN mas não consegui ainda achar uma boa motivação pra ele. O que eu li é que o OWIN é uma forma de desacoplar o aplicativo do servidor pra podermos trocar o servidor se preciso sem afetar o aplicativo.

Até aí tudo bem, mas eu não consigo ver isso como uma motivação muito forte. Por exemplo, em todos os projetos que eu já trabalhei e inclusive no que estou trabalhando agora, eu não consigo ver razão nenhuma pra mudar do IIS. Dizem também la na MSDN que OWIN é uma forma de otimizar aplicativos para a nuvem, mas eu não consigo ver de que forma isso se relaciona com desacoplar aplicativo e servidor e de que forma o OWIN permite isso.

Então, afinal, qual é a real necessidade para OWIN? Por quê ele otimiza aplicativos para a nuvem?

Answer (score 3):

Essa tecnologia permite, por exemplo, substituir a necessidade do IIS para se servir websites ou webservices. A motivação é a flexibilidade, o que no caso de se substituir o IIS pode significar mais performance.

Imagine um sistema pequeno, exista com o mero propósito de ouvir uma porta qualquer e fornecer alguns serviços usando uma interface REST... tipo, na máquina local mesmo, você quer fazer um serviço para localizar arquivos na máquina. Ai você tinha duas alternativas: ouvir as requisições na mão, e implementar um pipeline de resposta à requisição, usando Socket, ou então implementar um webservice que usa IIS... agora existe uma terceira opção, que é implementar a interface OWIN, que é mais simples do que fazer tudo na mão, e não requer um bulldozer (IIS) só pra carregar umas pedrinhas.

**Referência:**

[When should I use OWIN Katana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308585/when-should-i-use-owin-katana)