# Como "chamar" uma página ASP.NET sem usar IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, owin

Preciso obter via programação, o resultado do processamento de uma página em ASP.NET, mas não posso usar o IIS.

O certo, seria, se o ASP.NET, tivesse um CGI para ser chamado, assim como o PHP possui, mas não encontrei nada, somente o `mono_cgi` mas pelo que vi funciona somente para Linux.

Pseudocódigo que preciso:

```
processePagina("c:\caminho\para\meu\aspx\index.aspx", "url.ficticia?param1=valor1.....")
```

Este código tem que retornar o mesmo que o *browser* receberia se tivesse acessando o arquivo pelo IIS.

Detalhe, não posso usar o IIS Hostable Web Core, pois não posso instalar nada no computador do cliente e tem que suportar Windows XP.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Se você não pode instalar nada, como você vai colocar seu software? Existe o [OWIN](http://owin.org/) que talvez ajude, mas é difícil garantir sem entender o problema real. Você pode usar um serviço externo, colocar esta página em um local hospedado e acessá-lo como `HttpClient` ou alguma solução semelhante. Dá para bolar algumas soluções mas provavelmente todas serão estranhas. Talvez seu problema seja outro. Eu fico tentando imaginar porque alguém que não pode ter o IIS instalado teria uma página `aspx` que precisasse ser renderizada. Não achei um motivo.

Comment: São requisitos da especificação. 1) A instalação deve ser feita totalmente automatizada, somente exibir progresso para o usuário, usuário clicou no exe e instala sozinho. 2) Tem que rodar windows xp (.net framework 4.0 já vai estar instalado na máquina do cliente). É um aplicativo que vai ser instalado no computador do cliente, mas a interface de configuração será feita via browser, ou seja, o cliente acessará http://localhost:8080

Comment: O Mongoose faz extamente o que eu to querendo... dá uma olhada https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

Comment: O ideal é [edit]ar e colocar na pergunta todas as informações possíveis que ajudem as pessoas entenderem o problema e facilitem para ajudar você. Ainda não consegui entender qual o seu real problema. mas não importa, parece que você já achou exatamente o que você está querendo.

Comment: é a mesma questão que essa aqui.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423097/is-it-possible-to-use-katana-to-host-an-existing-webforms-application-within-a-w

Comment: achei mais coisa: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23939/Light-IIS-Run-Asp-net-without-IIS

Comment: http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/

Comment: OWIN foi a primeira coisa que eu falei. E ainda disse que existem inúmeras soluções possíveis. Mas é possível que você nem precise de tudo isto, o problema pode ser outro, você pode ter achado uma solução que causou um problema extra. Você achou a solução que desejava, certo?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [OWIN](http://owin.org/) para ter um servidor HTTP embutido na aplicação sem ter que instalar nada extra. Na página *linkada* tem a informação inicial e outras tecnologias associadas que serão úteis, especialmente o [Katana](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/october/asp-net-getting-started-with-the-katana-project?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que eu acho que é a implementação do OWIN que você precisa (ele é um servidor para embutir na sua aplicação, ou seja, não precisa instalar nada a não ser a sua própria aplicação).

Também pode saber algo mais aqui mesmo no SOpt: [OWIN e Katana - Como realmente funciona e como usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16139/owin-e-katana-como-realmente-funciona-e-como-usar) e [Motivação para OWIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14227/motiva%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-owin).

Existem outras soluções mas eu não as usaria não ser que tenha um motivo que inviabilize o OWIN. Esta solução tem apoio da Microsoft, é moderna e ativa, não posso dizer o mesmo dos exemplos que você deu nos comentários.

> esse código tem que retornar o mesmo que o browser receberia se tivesse acessando o arquivo pelo IIS

Por outro lado se você quiser ler uma página servida para fazer alguma coisa com ela a melhor solução provavelmente seria o uso do [`WebClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) que é mais simples ou [`HttpWebRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) se precisar de algo mais poderoso. Acredito que esta seja a segunda parte do que você deseja.