# Como comunicar um aplicativo local com uma pagina web aberta no browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, aplicação-web

Tenho uma aplicação web comercial que executa operações básicas de um restaurante. 
Em síntese, um garçom acessa a página de 'pedidos' e solicita um novo 'produto'. Esses produtos são classificados por departamentos, e cada departamento tem uma impressora (térmica/matricial) onde será impresso o pedido solicitado!

Como os browsers não permitem que eu altere  a impressora a ser usada por parâmetros, o garçom teria que escolher a impressora manualmente, o que é completamente inviável!

Ontem, discutindo a respeito aqui no SO, me sugeriram criar um aplicativo, que instalado localmente em meu cliente, pudesse servir de interface para essa impressão. Mas não faço a menor ideia de como fazer isso?

O que preciso é o seguinte:
***Quando o usuário envia a requisição de um novo produto ao servidor (via AJAX), se o JSON retornado for de sucesso, minha pagina 'avisa' a aplicação local (ou algo parecido) que seleciona a impressora responsável, e envia os cupons!***

Mas como faço essa comunicação? Exite algum protocolo?

Preciso de ao menos um rumo, por que ate agora, não sei nem onde começar!

Aplicação web desenvolvida em ASP.net MVC 4 com C# e SQLServer.. o aplicativo local ainda não foi escrito, e apesar de estarmos abertos a soluções em qualquer tecnologia, a preferencia é para C#,

Comment: Você vai ter que escrever um servidor web. A comunicação poderá ser por HTTP ou TCP com *websockts*.

Comment: @bigown.. neste caso como seria a comunicação? O aplicativo local se comunicaria com um webserver, que manteria um cache, por exemplo, de informações a imprimir?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso, além das atividades do webserver, você pode fazer qualquer coisa que você quiser nele. O browser nem saberá que está se comunicando com algo específico. Esse servidor precisa fazer tudo o que um browser espera (claro que pode ter algumas limitações bem tratadas). Já falei alguma coisa sobre isto em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31942/101

Comment: AJAX não e um linguagem e somente um protocolo. A pagina no servidor vai receber dados e vai responder. Um opçao seria criar um Applet JAVA. Como a Applet vai ser no "browser" ela vai pode imprimir localmente. Aqui tem uma pagina com explicações sobre um sistema deste tipo, para imprimir etiquetas. Os documentos são em Frances, mas Google Translator e suficiente para entender e as informaçoes são bem detalhadas.
http://lgl.isnetne.ch/d6ithemes/appletImpression.htm

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma maneira de fazer algo *semelhante*. Com uma aplicação `WindowsForms` você pode fazer um form simples que vai conter um componente `webBrowser` e com isso você consegue utilizar o próprio C# para realizar a configuração da impressora, executar algum outro aplicativo, ou fazer direto neste aplicativo.

Assim vc mantém toda a lógica de negócios no aplicativo web e trata de forma local a parte da impressora.

Segue um link que pode ajudar a ter uma ideia sobre o que eu falei:

http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/

Comment: isso seria bacana! Esse 'webBrowser' seria tipo uma guia do iexplorer? Ele depende do Browser do cliente ou é independente?

Comment: Até onde eu sei ele utiliza o IE, que é nativo do SO windows, para realizar a renderização das páginas da web. Porém caso seja necessário existem alguns tutoriais na web que mostram como criar um componente webbrowser utilizando o webkit, que o chrome utiliza, por exemplo. Cabe a você validar quais os sistemas operacionais que deverão ser suportados pela sua aplicação. Este caso que eu falei se aplica para Windows, se for para usar em IOS, que eu acho meio difícil pela sua descrição, ou em SO's baseados em linux não deve funcionar!