# Servidor web que receba e envie parâmetros para C#, é possível?

Tags: php, c#, html, aplicação-web

Desenvolvi um software em C# (.NET) que envia/recebe arquivos textos para um servidor FTP, mas por segurança procuro a trabalhar apenas com parâmetros dos tipos `String`/`Bytes` por razões de segurança, minha dúvida é: "possível criar um servidor web (não imagino em qual ferramenta/linguagem) que receba esses parâmetros via C# e me respondam quando solicitado?

Obs: Esses dados também vão ser solicitados via um App em Android.

Comment: Você pode descrever melhor essa funcionalidade desse novo servidor? Ficou um pouco confuso. Ele vai se comunicar com a ferramenta que comunica com o servidor FTP?

Comment: Olá, desculpe devo ter me expressado errado, seria apenas um servidor web que recebesse parâmetros e respondesse quando solicitado, obrigado!

Comment: Revisão do comentário acima, atualmente eu uso FTP e quero trocar por algum tipo de servidor básico que respondam essas necessidades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível, claro. Se não fosse possível não existiram servidores web, certo?

Precisa ver se é isto que você quer mesmo. Raramente isto é necessário. Mas se quiser ir em frente eu digo que não é tarefa fácil, principalmente porque parece que você se preocupa com segurança. Fazer um servidor seguro é extremamente difícil e trabalhoso, em geral feito por equipes muito experientes e totalmente dedicadas ao assunto.

Talvez exista uma solução que resolva o que você quer sem tanto trabalho. Não é o mais adequado para sites de grande movimento mas resolve necessidades específicas. A Microsoft criou algo que faz boa parte do trabalho. É uma especificação (OWIN) e uma implementação (Katana) de um servidor para usar com aplicações .NET. Escrevi alguma coisa [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31711/101). Lá tem links para mais informações sobre a tecnologia. Agora existe também o [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) que é a implementação multiplataforma do OWIN.

Mas reafirmo, eu acho que você não precisa de nada disto. Um servidor padrão deve resolver o que você precisa. O que você pede é a função de qualquer servidor.

Veja o [YARP](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/).

Comment: Com certeza amigo! Realmente é necessário, mas acho que recorrer a aplicação "Kestrel" é exagero, o que desejo imagino que não seja nada complicado, explicando melhor eu necessito de um SERVIDOR simples que recebesse e respondesse parâmetros, uma pequena observação eu uso C# Windows Form não C#ASP.NET, vou solicitar e enviar parâmetros via C# (Desktop) e Android (Mobile), então a pergunta seria: Qual servidor você me recomendaria? e como desenvolver (introdução), Obrigado!
(Segurança é o de menos, relação a isso se viramos por aqui)

Comment: Continuando o comentário acima: "Pode ser alguma aplicação parecida com FTP, você se direciona ao endereço ele apenas pede login e senha e fim... Só que sem interface e nada apenas um servidor de parâmetros, entende?

Comment: Eu respondi o que dá para responder. Estou dando a opção simples, se você prefere a complicada eu duvido que consiga aqui, nem caberia em uma resposta se for feito o mínimo que deve ser feito. Eu entendo que você não conheça o assunto e ache que é simples fazer algo assim mas não é.

Comment: Sim em relação a web não tenho muita experiência e conhecimento, É que pelo que pesquisei essas aplicações katana, owin são todas voltadas ao c#asp.net, certo? Eu prefiro uma opção simples e achei essas acima complicadas rsrssr

Comment: Sim mas não necessariamente precisa usar o ASP.Net. Pessoas experientes no assunto têm dificuldade de construir algo assim, sem experiência é melhor não tentar. E acho que a única solução é contratar alguém que comprovadamente já tenha feito algo assim e esteja em produção por um bom período sem problemas.

Comment: Entendo, mas não tenho outra opção a não ser recorrer a aprender e criar, vou aguardar mais respostas e pesquisar mais! Muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção, abraços.

Comment: @Pedro legal que aceitou, agora você ganhou o privilégio de votar em tudo o que desejar também, em coisas relacionadas ao que você postou ou não. Veja o [tour]