# É possível criar um site com HTML e C# sem ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

É possível criar um site somente com HTML e C#, sem ASP.NET? Em linhas gerais, como?

Comment: Isso é apenas curiosidade ou há outra motivação? De repente você tem a intenção de criar um site em C# sem ASP.NET para poder hospedar em servidores Linux ao invés de Windows....se fosse esse o caso, aí poderíamos mencionar outras soluções...apenas fiquei curioso com sua pergunta.

Comment: @Alisson Era só curiosidde mesmo!

Comment: @isaque de uma vista de olhos na [NancyFx](https://github.com/NancyFx/nancy). E uma forma de construir o site sem utilizar, nem depender no ASP.NET (MVC).

Comment: @Omni blz, vou olhar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sim, HTML é padrão. CSS também é quase obrigatório na prática. JS provavelmente será usado. Tudo isto no lado do cliente.

No lado do servidor pode usar virtualmente qualquer linguagem. C# é uma delas, e das mais viáveis. É uma das 3 linguagens mais usadas em toda web.

Não precisa usar ASP.NET clássico, mas é provável que queira usar alguma outra [tecnologia próxima disto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111209/101). Pode usar outras tecnologias que não o ASP.NET, pode pegar estas tecnologias que são *open source* e modificar para atender suas necessidades. Um exemplo é o [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/nancy) citado pelo Omni.

Se quiser pode reinventar a roda, mas mesmo eu que gosto disto para ter mais controle provavelmente não o faria.

Detalhar como fazer é muito amplo, mas as duas formas principais é usar a API do servidor web, provavelmente IIS ou Apache, mandando mensagens para ele do que deseja fornecer e receber mensagens dele de requisições ou usar [CGI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93308/101), aí basicamente é escrever no console e configurar para o servidor capturar isto. Cada servidor pode ter dua própria forma de comunicar com a aplicação servidora.

Precisa achar um bom motivo para fazer isto. Se for performance acho que tem outros meios melhores de alcançar o objetivo. Se for não ter que aprender uma tecnologia, provavelmente não compensa o esforço que terá que fazer na mão.

Note que é possível evitar o WebForms que é obsoleto e considerado ruim por muitos, ou mesmo evitar o MVC que é um pouco pesado, melhorou no ASP.NET Core, mas ainda é um canhão para matar passarinho em muitos casos. Tem problemas que não precisa de modelos e controladores. E é verdade que nos casos mais simples, a última coisa que vai querer fazer é comunicar com o servidor HTTP na mão. Para isto existe o [Razor Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

É bom lembrar que o ASP.NET Core possui [servidor HTTP próprio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40943/101), que pode ser usado em muitas situações, mas não em todas. E agora [conta até com *proxy* reverso](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy).

Tem perguntas no site com mais detalhes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Boa explicação. Se pararmos para pensar, já que o próprio ASP.NET foi desenvolvido em C#, nada nos impediria de criar uma biblioteca concorrente para desenvolvimento de aplicações web, mas como mencionado, isso seria reinventar a roda, correto?

Comment: @Alisson correto. Pode inclusive mexer no código existente já que ele é totalmente livre, livre no sentido de livre mesmo, não no sentido de GPL que não é livre de verdade.