# OWIN e OAuth O que são e como utilizar?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth2, owin

Estou vendo tutoriais de WebApi com autenticação/autorização e me deparei com este dois conceitos, embora explicados nos tutoriais as definições não são claras.

Mesmo pesquisando na web, as explicações em inglês são confusas (para mim) e em português também não ajudaram.

Comment: Vou comentar porque não saberia dar uma resposta completa: Em resumo, são métodos de autenticação HTTP. São simplesmente diferentes esquemas que o HTTP fornece pra autenticação.

Comment: Em alguns exemplos, vi que os dois são utilizados simultaneamente. Pode resumir a resposta, não precisa ser uma resposta detalhada.

Comment: Dado o comentário resolvi responder, não sei se será suficiente mas acho que você já sabe que a pergunta beira a ser muito ampla. Além de estar perguntando sobre duas coisas, pedir como usar sem contexto, sem um problema específico, fica complicado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O [OWIN](http://owin.org/) (Open Web Interface for .NET) é uma solução para generalizar o acesso da aplicação ao hospedeiro. Antes dele existir para rodar o ASP.NET era necessário o IIS ou teria que modificar os próprios componentes do ASP.NET para usar outro *host*. O IIS era uma dependência, e pior, os componentes que se comunicam com o IIS eram pesados.

Na nova filosofia do .NET de ter soluções mais abertas era necessário criar uma maneira padrão de comunicação entre a aplicação e o *host*, permitindo assim a utilização de outros *hosts*, inclusive a própria aplicação cuidar disto, e a comunicação pode ser feita de forma mais flexível, leve, personalizada para cada situação.

O OWIN é justamente a especificação de como essa comunicação funciona. Algumas implementações desta especificação são: [Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que permite o *self-host* da aplicação, o [Helios](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/introducing-asp-net-project-helios/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que permite o uso com o IIS.

Tem uma [resposta sobre o seu uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14227/101) aqui no site.

O [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) é um padrão também, uma especificação de como aplicações deve autorizar. Não importa se a aplicação é para a web, mobile ou desktop, desde que ela se comunique da forma padrão especificada e através de protocolo HTTP.

Você pode usar provedores de autorização diversos, fornecido por você de forma isolada, ou, o mais comum, através de terceiros. Assim você não precisa se preocupar com o processo todo, apenas precisa saber se o usuário está autorizado ou não.

Desta forma, dados que precisam estar seguros ficam fora da aplicação e provavelmente na mão de quem sabe mantê-los seguro e possui a confiança do dono da informação. A aplicação só recebe o que for relevante para ela.

Uma implementação do padrão para .NET é o [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/). Com ele você só precisa aprender a API e não tem que se preocupar com o padrão em si. Existem outras implementações. O OWIN usa o [OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para isto.

[Artigo na Wikipedia sobre ele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Como fiquei parado no tempo (com relação webapi), meu último contado foi com `Self-Host ASP.NET Web API 1`. Agora com essa sopa de letras `OWIN/OAuth` a confusão foi garnde. OWIN seria uma evolução do `Self-Host ASP.NET Web API 1`? Caso positivo poderia adicionar esta observação a resposta.

Comment: De uma certa forma é uma evolução sim, mas agora feito do jeito certo, antes era uma bela de uma gambiarra que tinha muitos defeitos e carregava componentes desnecessários. OWIN é muito mais que isto e ele nem precisa ser *self-host*, esta é apenas uma das formas dele ser usado. O Katana é uma implementação do OWIN que funciona *self-host*. OAuth é algo completamente separado.

Comment: @bigown li na sua resposta mencionar que o OAUTH é para autenticar aplicações. Utilizo este protocolo e tenho a noção que se trata de AUTORIZAÇÃO e não AUTENTICAÇÃO...estou certo?

Comment: @chambelix está sim, é bem óbvio que é isto na página dele. Foi um lapso meu, vou consertar. Obrigado.