# ASP.NET precisa de um servidor Windows?

Tags: asp.net, windows

De costume para PHP eu instalado sempre Debian e Apache, porém quero me aprofundar melhor no desenvolvimento web e pretendo dar uma olhada em ASP.NET, por curiosidade me veio a dúvida se irei precisar de um servidor Windows caso for executar em um ambiente de produção.

É necessário ter um servidor Windows para rodar essa linguagem? Ouvi falar que tem um módulo no Apache que faz isso, porém terá a mesma performance?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema, sua dúvida? Precisa de ajuda?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O ASP.NET clássico, aquele que surgiu desde o princípio do .NET é considerada agora uma tecnologia legada. Ela ainda será suportada, mas não deve receber atualizações significativas. Nem vou falar nela então. E não é uma linguagem.

O [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é uma tecnologia mais nova e está saindo agora uma nova [versão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49090/101), que faz parte de uma coleção de tecnologias chamada de [ASP.ET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101). É importante não confundir com o ASP.NET 4.6 que é o clássico e tem fim de linha decretado.

O ASP.NET MVC dependia um pouco do ASP.NET. De uma certa forma ele dependia do IIS. Na verdade, nem tanto porque existe o ASP.NET para o [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) que roda no Linux, portanto [pode usar Apache](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/). A performance não é ótima, mas ainda muito boa. Estamos falando do uso de C# que é uma linguagem estática e compilada, então isto conta muito.

Agora existe o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) (está saindo do forno) que roda em diversas plataformas e o no ASP.NET Core foi remodelado para funcionar bem em todas as plataformas. Com esta nova distribuição o próprio .NET da Microsoft (não é uma implementação alternativa de terceiros) passa suportar integralmente e com todo apoio, Linux e MacOS.

O principal motivo para a criação do .NET Core é poder rodar bem o ASP.NET Core nessas plataformas usando a tecnologia de servidor que bem entender.

Essa abstração do servidor de aplicação foi obtida pela implementação do [OWIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76609/101). Hoje o ASP.NET pode rodar sem um servidor externo.

O Mono tende a ser legado nestas plataformas, na maioria dos cenários. Hoje se quiser usar com Apache ([mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/)), ele ainda é necessário. Não há nada no .NET Core que funcione com ele. Isto pode mudar. Há maneiras de usar o novo ASP.NET como *self-host* mais o [Nginx](http://nginx.org/).

De fato, agora [deve sobreviver apenas o .NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Depende do que as tecnologias `.NET` específicas que você está usando. O Projeto [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page/) fornece um módulo do Apache (`mod_mono`) para permitir aplicações ASP.net nas três plataformas Windows, Linux e MAC.

O Mono não suportar todas as APIs .NET, mas suporta WCF.

Sobre a performance, encontrei um `performance test`, mas ele é de 2008 e naquela época .NET foi 6 vezes mais rápido que mono. [Veja](https://web.archive.org/web/20200120120611/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/CISCBrain/archive/2005/08/28/Mono_vs_dotNet_Performance_Test.aspx)