# Diferenças entre tipos de autenticação

Tags: node.js, autenticação, autenticação-http

Estava pesquisando um pouco sobre autenticação, pois pretendo melhorar essa parte de um sistema meu, encontrei alguns casos como Basic, oAuth1 e oAuth2.

Qual a diferença entre eles? O que realmente são? Li um pouco sobre, mas não consegui compreender muito ainda.
Posso desenvolver um sistema oAuth? Ou dependo de algo?

Pretendo desenvolver minha nova API com NodeJS + Mysql (Atualmente é PHP + Mysql) e futuramente migrar para NodeJS + MongoDB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Basic

É um método que o [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) (uma linha de texto que identifica o browser e o SO para o servidor web) usa para prover nome de usuário e senha quando faz uma requisição. É a técnica mais simples de controle de acesso porque não requer cookies ou identificadores de sessão, em vez disso usa campos padrão no cabeçalho HTTP. Também não garante muita segurança ao aplicativo.

### oAuth

Basicamente oAuth (Open authorization) é um protocolo de autorização seguro que trata da autorização de aplicativos de terceiros para acessar alguns dados sem expor a senha.

Algumas [diferenças](https://hueniverse.com/introducing-oauth-2-0-b5681da60ce2) entre oAuth1 e oAuth2:

- Melhor suporte para aplicativos que não é um navegador web. Este é um ponto importante com relação oAuth1, onde aplicativos desktop ou mobile tinham que direcionar o usuário para o navegador. Com oAuth2 existem novas maneiras de um aplicativo obter autorização.
- Assinaturas oAuth2 são menos complicadas
- Um propósito de oAuth2 é ter separação clara entre funções do servidor responsável de solicitações e o servidor que gerencia a autorização do usuário.
- Os tokens de acesso são mais curtos em oAuth2
- oAuth2 não exige que aplicativos clientes tenha criptografia

Mais detalhes estão no artigo acima.

### Em termos práticos para node.js

Existem formas diretas e simples de implementar autenticação baseada em oAuth com node.js usando bibliotecas já existentes. É necessário existir servidores de autorização, que pode ser criado ou poderia ser o Facebook, Github, Twitter, Gmail ou qualquer outro serviço.

Uma biblioteca que implementa oAuth2 é [passportjs](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-oauth2/). Recomendo estuda-lá (a implementação não é traumática e existem vários exemplos), onde é possível configurar a estratégia de autenticação - *Usuário* e *Senha* ou *Facebook* por exemplo. Então, na verdade quem vai autorizar o cliente de se conectar ao aplicativo irá ser a comunicação entre servidor de acesso (sua aplicação) e o servidor de autorização (Facebook). O usuário não irá precisar incluir usuário e senha.

Fontes para estudos mais específicos:

- Stack Overflow em Português - [OAuth - O que é? Qual sua finalidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123777/oauth-o-que-%C3%A9-qual-sua-finalidade)
- Wikipedia - [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- Stack Overflow - [How is OAuth 2 different from OAuth 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113934/how-is-oauth-2-different-from-oauth-1)
- Quora - [How do I build a Node.js REST API with OAuth 2?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-build-a-Node-js-REST-API-with-OAuth-2)
- Site oficial do Passport.js - http://passportjs.org/

Comment: No meu caso, estou construindo uma API que sera utilizada no meu APP (Mobile, IOS e Android), e meu Dashboard (WEB). Acha que qual seria apropriada ?

Comment: Eu particularmente nunca criei a API de autorização oAuth, sempre usei as mais comuns, usei Facebook e Gitbub. Dificilmente algum usuário não ter Facebook por exemplo. Mas caso o cliente vai ser outra API (não um usuário propriamente dito) aí talvez é mais apropriado você criar o seu servidor, caso contrário o caminho feliz pode ser melhor custo/beneficio.

Comment: No caso, meu app tera login via Facebook, porem, tambem tera opcao de se cadastrar por formulario, ja o dashboard, nao existira login via facebook.

Comment: Você pode usar a básica e pelo facebook então. Ou criar o servidor se quiser maior segurança e praticidade para o usuário.