# Como uma aplicação WEB que usa o OAuth para autentificação consegue gerenciar a sessão do usuário?

Tags: session, login, autenticação, oauth2, oauth

Geralmente sessões são usadas para manter dados de um determinado usuário após ele ter logado na aplicação WEB, e é a aplicação WEB que fica responsável pelo controle e gerenciamento desses dados armazenados na sessão. Ela pode usar isso para identificar o usuário que esta logado no sistema e outros fins.

Mas quando eu li a respeito do protocolo [OAuth](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123777/oauth-o-que-%C3%A9-qual-sua-finalidade), eu não compreendi muito bem como que uma aplicação WEB (client-oauth) que permite que um usuário faça login usando sua conta do Google, consegue gerenciar a sessão e manter ela ativa e identificar o usuário logado ou saber quando o usuário esta logado.

Em tese, não seria o próprio Google (serve-oauth) que deveria gerenciar a sessão ao invés da aplicação WEB que usou o OAuth para autentificar o usuário?

## Resumindo

1. Como uma aplicação WEB que usa OAuth para autentificação, consegue gerenciar a sessão e
   identificar o usuário que está logado, ou saber se ele está logado?
2. Quais tipos de dados uma aplicação WEB que usa OAuth para autentificação recebe como
   resposta do servidor OAuth quando o usuário é autenticado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras. Antes, vamos às perguntas:

> Em tese, não seria o próprio Google (serve-oauth) que deveria gerenciar a sessão ao invés da aplicação WEB que usou o OAuth para autentificar o usuário?

Não. Google é responsável pela autenticação do usuário e pela verificação da validade das requisições de informações do usuário feitas pelas aplicações web.

> Como uma aplicação WEB que usa OAuth para autentificação, consegue gerenciar a sessão e identificar o usuário que está logado, ou saber se ele está logado?

Ela mesma gerenciaria as sessões; o provedor OAuth só valida acessos à informação de seus usuários registrados.

> Quais tipos de dados uma aplicação WEB que usa OAuth para autentificação recebe como resposta do servidor OAuth quando o usuário é autenticado?

Existem vários formatos, mas em geral o fluxo é desenhado para segregar camadas - via web o usuário se valida, e a aplicação recebe um *token* que deve ser re-validado diretamente pelo servidor - e só aí o *back-end* da aplicação obterá os dados do usuário que está se logando.

Acho que o fluxo pode ser melhor visualizado se os passos forem listados em sequência:

- A sua aplicação web é registrada junto ao provedor OAuth. Este irá gerar uma chave secreta, que você utilizará no futuro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Usuário se conecta à sua aplicação web. Sem sessão ativa, você oferece uma página contendo uma lista de provedores OAuth que o usário pode utilizar. O usuário seleciona, por exemplo, Google.
- O browser é redirecionado para o provedor OAuth2 do Google, junto com uma URL de retorno válida (previamente cadastrada - na imagem acima, `http://localhost` foi utilizada).
- Usuário se autentica.
- Google redireciona de volta, junto com um token de requisição.
- O seu servidor recebe uma requisição do *browser* que contém o *token* de requisição - algo como `http://localhost/?token=1234567`.
- O servidor estabelece uma conexão direta para o *back-end* OAuth do Google, passando tanto o *token* recebido quanto sua chave secreta (por exemplo, `https://oauth.google.com/validate/?token=1234567&secret-key=abcdefgh`.)
- O provedor Oauth valida se token, chave secreta e URL de origem são válidos. Caso positivo, *um payload* é retornado contendo os dados do usuário (JSON: `{'email': 'teste@gmail.com'}`, por exemplo.)
- Sua aplicação cria sua própria sessão, baseada nas informações retornadas pelo  backend Oauth2 do Google.

Dois pontos importantes:

- Sua aplicação web nunca recebe as credenciais (email + password) diretamente - estas são validadas nos servidores do Google.
- Seu *front-end* nunca recebe a chave-secreta, já que esta deve ser utilizada apenas pelo *back-end*.

Comment: Fiz uma implementação aqui, usando uma lib para logar no google, mas ele dá um erro por causa da minha URL de redirecionamento q está apontando para uma pagina no localhost, url: `http://localhost/oauth2-exemplo-google/restrito.php`. A descrição do erro eh *redirect_uri_mismatch*. Como eu posso testar em localhost?

Comment: @gato `//localhost` é um endereço válido. Talvez o protocolo esteja diferente (`https` ao invés de `http`, por exemplo.)

Comment: Eu estava apontando para a pagina errada :P. E tive q trocar `oauth2-exemplo-google/restrito.php` por `oauth2-exemplo-google/restrito/`, e funcionou.