# Posso rodar o ASP.NET no Nginx sem o Kestrel?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, nginx, proxy

É possível hospedar o meu site ASP.NET diretamente no Nginx, igual faria com o PHP? Sem a necessidade de usar o Kestrel e Nginx apenas como um *proxy* reverso.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 1):

Boa pergunta.

[Isso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows) indica que não, mas não tenho certeza se for usar o Nginx de forma tradicional. Só que eu procurei e não achei nada que confirmasse que dê.

O que eu posso te dizer com certeza é que se for usar o Nginx como *proxy* reverso, o Kestrel ou outro mecanismo semelhante a ele, é obrigatório.

Dá para fazer se você criar sua própria implementação do [OWIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76609/101), mas não sei se é o que deseja, ou se vale a pena. Pra falar a verdade eu acho que não é necessário fazer isso. Hoje eu acho que apenas não dá, de forma tradicional, só porque ninguém criou um OWIN para isso.

O que eu sei é que logo poderá usar o [YARP](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-yarp-preview-1/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e talvez seja o melhor caminho, estão criado ele porque o Nginx se mostrou limitante. Então não tome o Kestrel como um dificultador, abrace-o.